# Postfix access and subdomains?

Tags: postfix

I am trying to include in my `/etc/postfix/access` some domains from known spammers I would like to block (please no discussion if this is useful or not....).

Accordings to the documentation it should discard any incoming mails from spam domain with the following entry in the access file:

```
.spam.domain.de   DISCARD Spam rule domain block
```

The related config setting (smtpd_access_maps) is enabled:

```
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
```

And the access file is configured, too:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
[...]
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
```

So I would expect Postfix to discard all mails received from a domain `news.spam.domain.de`, `letter.spam.domain.de` or even `spam.domain.de`.

But it does **not**. So I tried to debug with postmap:

```
root@mail:~# postmap access
root@mail:~# postmap -q news.spam.domain.de access; echo $?
1
root@mail:~# postmap -q spam.domain.de access; echo $?
1
root@mail:~# postmap -q .spam.domain.de access; echo $?
DISCARD Spam rule domain block
0
```

Looks like it matches only the *exact* string.

Anyone having an idea what I got wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The `-q` flag only checks if the following string is in the file verbatim.

> https://linux.die.net/man/1/postmap
>
> -q key
>
> Search the specified maps for key and write the first value found to
> the standard output stream. The exit status is zero when the requested
> information was found.

It does not actually do a check of whether or not the subdomain you entered is allowed to send you email.

This is a line from `/etc/postfix/access`:

```
gmail.com       OK
```

This is the output of `postmap -q /etc/postfix/access; echo $?`:

```
[root]# postmap -q bob@gmail.com /etc/postfix/access; echo $?
1
[root]# postmap -q gmail.com /etc/postfix/access; echo $?
OK
0
```